# Using Low Replace and Low Nice Date Together

Tags: low, low-replace, low-nice-date

The database has a string which is a date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy (13/03/2014). No, it has not been saved to the database as a proper date/time.

With Low Replace we are able to change the format of this to yyyy/mmm/dd

```
{exp:low_replace find="/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/" replace="$3/$2/$1" regex="yes"}
  13/03/2014
{/exp:low_replace}
```

Is it possible to apply Nice Date to the date after Replace has done it's thing as nice date won't work with dd/mm/yyyy? Or do we need to use something like Stash to create a variable for Nice date to work with once Replace has converted it?

Comment: Are you able to change the values of the date in the DB? You could change the format to dd-mm-yyyy with one query, which would remove the need of using Low Replace altogether.

Comment: Thanks Low, I think that will probably be what we end up doing. Not sure how to close this questions now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend changing the value of the date field to dd-mm-yyyy so you don't need to use Low Replace, and instead can use the value directly into Low Nice Date. The query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_X = REPLACE(field_id_X, '/', '-');
```

Where X is the field ID in question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck with this...

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{exp:low_replace find="/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/" replace="$3/$2/$1" regex="yes"}13/03/2014{/exp:low_replace}" format="%F %Y" parse="inward"}
```

If that works, consider moving the low_replace into a snippet so it's easier to read

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{sn_fixed-date}" format="%F %Y" parse="inward"}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for the advice. Looks like that doesn't work.